# Поиск в массивах JavaScript

Tags: javascript, массивы

Добрый вечер, имеются 10 массивов, необходимо сделать поиск по их содержимому.
Мол, если символ встречается в одном из массивов, вернуть его индекс.
Вопрос.
Пытался сделать цикл, который будет просто брать массив i смотреть содержимое и идти дальше... Но я не знаю как обращаться к разным массивам в цикле, ведь надо менять имена циклов.
Можете подсказать!?
Заранее благодарен!

```js
    var _1 = ["1"];
    _2 = ["A","B","C",'2'];
    _3 = ["D","E","F", "3"];
    _4 = ["G","H","I", "4"];
    _5 = ["J","K","L", "5"];
    _6 = ["M","N","O", "6"];
    _7 = ["P","Q","R","S","7"];
    _8 = ["T","U","V", "8"];
    _9 = ["W","X","Y","Z","9"];
    _0 = [" ","0"];
```

Comment: Это уже неправильно, что они не лежат в одном массиве/объекте

Comment: @Etki, Ситуации разные бывают. Хотя в таком случае использовал бы я `Array.prototype.concat`.

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так: Передаём все массивы одним массивом и что искать в функцию и возвращается массив с массивом, в котором есть заданный текст и позиция в этом элементе.

```js
var _1 = ["1"],
   _2 = ["A", "B", "C", '2'],
   _3 = ["D", "E", "F", "3"],
   _4 = ["G", "H", "I", "4"],
   _5 = ["J", "K", "L", "5"],
   _6 = ["M", "N", "O", "6"],
   _7 = ["P", "Q", "R", "S", "7"],
   _8 = ["T", "U", "V", "8"],
   _9 = ["W", "X", "Y", "Z", "9"],
   _0 = [" ", "0"];

function search(arrays, target){
  var arr = null, pos = 0, tmp = 0;
  
  if(Array.isArray(arrays)){
    arrays.forEach(function(a){
      if((tmp = a.indexOf(target)) !== -1){
        arr = a;
        pos = tmp;
      }
    });
  
    if(arr !== null)
      return [arr, pos];
    else
      return null;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}

var tmp = search([_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _0], "R");
var array = tmp[0]; // Массив, в котором найден элемент
var pos   = tmp[1]; // Позиция элемента в массиве
console.info(tmp, array[pos]); // [Array[5], 2] "R"
```

Answer (score 1):

Это мой вариант, так же передаете символ, возвращает ключ массива, ключ символа и символ

```
handler(sym){
for(i=1;i=<10;i++){
  for(j=0;j<window['_'+i].length;j++){
    if(window['_'+i][j] == sym)
      return [i,j,sym]
  }
}
}
alert(handler("A"));//[1,0,"A"]
```

Comment: контекст необязательно будет называться `window`, используйте `this`

Comment: @Etki, и что тут прототип нужно создавать? У автора все массивы отдельные переменные, вот и я решил обращаться каждому по отдельному

Comment: я про то, что в каком-нибудь nodejs window может не быть вообще в принципе

Comment: window['_'+i].length.... Ошибка, неизвестно что такое length.